# Ubuntu webapp-container doesn't allow using different input source

Tags: webapps, ibus, fcitx

I've created a `.desktop` file for  accessing web-based version of wechat , specifically file is `~/.local/share/applications/wechat.desktop` , with the following contents.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WeChat
Type=Application
Exec=webapp-container --name="WeChat" --icon=/home/xieerqi/.local/share/applications/wechat.png "http://wx.qq.com" 
Icon=/home/xieerqi/.local/share/applications/wechat.png
Terminal=false
```

With `sogou` pinyin input method, I cannot switch the language to Chinese, it stays in English even though I manually change it via indicator and such. Had similar experience with `ibus` pinyin, but at least in case of `ibus` I could input chinese text after multiple switching attempts. That leads me to believe the issue is primarily with `webapp-container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tweaking settings a bit, I finally came to a ( sort of ) solution  - explicitly declare user agent, via `--user-agent-string="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"`  option. Full `Exec=` line now looks like so:

```
webapp-container --webapp='V2VDaGF0Cg==' --app-id='WeChatWebApp' -d 'wx.qq.com' --user-agent-string="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"
```

This does allow switching input source and using sogou pinyin properly ( although not tested with ibus ) and solves occasional complains by WeChat's web service that I need to use "desktop browser" despite the fact that I am on a desktop.